# How to select objects from an NSArray that are contained in another NSArray using a predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate, nsindexpath

I have an `NSArray` of objects each of with contain a "key" field

I have another `NSArray` with nested `NSArrays` grouping those objects by a different field "group by field" for instance a display name (alphabetic grouping)

For instance

```
@interface MyObject

@property (nonatomic) int key;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *groupByKey;

@end


NSArray *aBounchOfObjectsInAFlatList = @[obj1,obj2,obj3....];

NSArray *groupByArrayOfObjects = @[@[obj1_tag,obj2_tag],@[objn_tag,objk_tag]....];
```

Important to note that `obj1 != obj1_tag` - they only share values of "groupByKey" and/or "key".

I would like to find the index of each obj_tag where `(obj_tag.key == obj.key)` from the flat array.

Now I am running 2 loops and saving the counter values - creating index paths for the matches.

I assume there is a clear way using `NSPredicates` to create an array of `NSIndexPaths` for the corresponding objects but I am not clear how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSPredicate` is just a predicate and nothing more. It is applied to some object and
yields YES or NO. A predicate can be used for *filtering* an array, but since the predicate itself is applied to each single array element, it does not "know" the location
(or index) of the object being tested. 
Therefore a `NSPredicate` cannot create an array of `NSIndexPath`s.

The `NSArray` method `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` can be useful to find the location
of an object in an array, but even that method has to loop over all array elements
to find the object. So it might help to make the code shorter or better readable, but
it does not change the performance.

If `groupByArrayOfObjects` is *really large*, then you can create a mapping (an `NSDictionary`) from each key to the corresponding index path first. This requires only one enumeration of the (nested) array. Then you can use this mapping to get
the index path for each element in the other array `aBounchOfObjectsInAFlatList`.

Comment: Ok, I thought there was something equivalent to a sql "select where" or LINQ select using NSPredicates. Seems then I must iterate over all objects.